# Webpack does not transpile process.env values correctly

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

Having following configuration:

**package.json**

```
"webpack": "^4.44.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
"webpack-merge": "^5.1.4",
"webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')})

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  target: 'node',
  
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.mjs'],
  },
  module: {
  
    rules: [
      ...
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": dotenv.parsed
    })
  ]
}
```

**Some file referencing env**

```
export const env = process.env;
```

**.env**

```
ENV="dev"
PORT="4007"
NEO4J_URI='bolt://ec2-11-11-11-11.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7687'
NEO4J_USER="neo4j"
NEO4J_PASSWORD="xxx"
AWS_PROFILE="xxx"
AWS_PROFILE_TRANSLATOR="xxx"
S3_NAME="xxx"
JWT_SECRET="xxx"
JWT_EXPIRATION="4h"
CLOUDWATCH_GROUP_NAME="xxx"
CLOUDWATCH_ACCESS_KEY="xxx"
CLOUDWATCH_SECRET_KEY="xxx"
CLOUDWATCH_REGION="xxx"
```

The problem is that in bundle file, particular part of code looks as follows:
[image: result.js]

As you can see, webpack wrongly transpile process.env reference to some definition, which seems to be object, but values are not strings (they should be), which leads to property of .env 'NEO4J_URI' value contains double slashes and as they are not string, it results to commented code. Please, does anybody know how to handle this?

Comment: Escaping by backslash in .env does not work

Comment: Tried using https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin to do the work for you?

Comment: Thanks for advice, but still does not work. I have created simple test repository reflecting the issue with environment plugin, where process.env is empty object on start.
https://github.com/zedefi/test-dotenv-webpack

Comment: I have found that the problem is with assignment of process.env to variable. For some reason, it is not possible. My second commit in repo mentioned above shows the probem where console.log of my variable does not contain any properties of process.env.

Comment: Please put your [mcve] in your post, don't put it on a github repo. Details to a post should be in the post, even if you also provide a link to a jsbin or site or repo etc.